# suddenly all my windows closed

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, window-manager

I was working in Linux Mint 20.2 with XFCE 4.16 and some keyboard shortcut suddenly closed all my windows except the one I was working in. I have no idea what I did. I reopened Brave and instead of getting all my tabs back like usual, I had none. Eeek! But then I found them all in a dropdown from the upper right corner. Clicking one reopened the whole window, so that was a relief. But everything else I was using has to be reopened. This isn't the first time I've accidentally used a keyboard shortcut and didn't know what I did or how to reverse it.

Does anybody know what caused this? I'd like to disable it, because closing all windows isn't something I would ever do intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have used one of the `Workspace` shortcuts, i.e., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>.

If this is the case, you can disable it by going into settings>workspaces (or just type `workspace` into the search bar) and changing the number of workspaces to 1. Changing workspaces doesn't close the applications, it just gives you a virtual "clean" desktop.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I had any other workspaces! I found one with a few of the windows I had been using, but not all... Testing shows that if I open Brave in a new workspace and open a page from the dropdown I mentioned, the entire window moves to the new workspace. That explains why Brave is missing from the other. But if I open LibreOffice in the new workspace and close it, it stays in the first. So I don't know what happened to the other windows I had...

Comment: Now that I know how, I might start using this feature. I've tried to use session manager to save my desktop when I shut down, but it doesn't work at all. This at least kept some of the windows when I shut down...